# Passing the type of the dependent object to the dependency in unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using Unity for dependency injection.  I want to be able to inject my logger into all classes that depend on it.  My problem is that they logger has a constructor argument that needs the `Type` of the object that's referencing it.  If I were using Ninject, I'd use the [Logging extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.logging/wiki).  How would I do the same in Unity?

Here's some sample code to show exactly what I mean.

```
public class Service1:IService1
{
    private ILog _log;
    public Service1(ILog log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _log.Print();
    }
}

public class Service2:IService2
{
    private ILog _log;
    public Service2(ILog log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _log.Print();
    }
}

public class Log:ILog
{
    private Type _ownerType;
    public Log(Type ownerType)
    {
        _ownerType = ownerType;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.Writeline("Owner:  {0}", _ownerType.Name);
    }
}

unityContainer.RegisterType<IService1, Service1>();
unityContainer.RegisterType<IService2, Service2>();
unityContainer.RegisterType<ILog, Log>()  // This is wrong

var s1 = unityContainer.Resolve<IService1>();
var s2 = unityContainer.Resolve<IService2>();

s1.DoSomething(); // Should print "Owner:  Service1"
s2.DoSomething(); // Should print "Owner:  Service2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Think in can help you, but I haven`t used Unity, so..

http://davidkeaveny.blogspot.ru/2011/03/unity-and-log4net.html

Hope, it will help you.

Comment: That link has very little content aside from a link to http://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/203744. The code on the CodePlex page doesn't compile as is and appears to be missing references.

Answer (score 0):

You could register the logger as open generic type and then in each service, resolve a closed generic of the class resolving the logger.

```
public class Service1:IService1
{
    private ILog _log;
    public Service1(ILog<Service1> log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _log.Print();
    }
}

public class Service2:IService2
{
    private ILog _log;
    public Service2(ILog<Service2> log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _log.Print();
    }
}

public interface ILog
{
    void Print();
}

public interface ILog<T> : ILog 
{
    //Any type specific methods
}

public class Log<T> : ILog<T>
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.Writeline("Owner:  {0}", typeof(T).Name);
    }
}

unityContainer.RegisterType<IService1, Service1>();
unityContainer.RegisterType<IService2, Service2>();
unityContainer.RegisterType(typeof(ILog<>), typeof(Log<>))

var s1 = unityContainer.Resolve<IService1>();
var s2 = unityContainer.Resolve<IService2>();

s1.DoSomething(); // Should print "Owner:  Service1"
s2.DoSomething(); // Should print "Owner:  Service2"
```

Comment: That's the code I'm trying to replace.  The problem with the open generic solution my ILog<T> is leaking implementation details to every class that uses it.  The fact that my implementation of ILog wants to know who uses it has no impact on how it is used.

Comment: I think of it as a shortcut instead of a leaked implementation detail.  Another valid option would be to have a parameter to Print of the type.  That gets long winded to have to pass in the type on every call to Print, so adding that to the constructor or as a generic parameter to the type is just a shortcut.  It's not an implementation detail because it really is just an input to the method in a different way.